# Facebook "via appname" not clickable on profile feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, xcode4.5

I have an application which uploads link and photos to facebook. I have linked it to my app facebook page in app settings at developer.facebook.com. There are two scenarios.

1) When i upload a link with some text. The "via <**Appname**>" is clickable from both my **Home** and **Profile**.

```
[FB requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [[self.recipeDetails objectForKey:@"source"] objectForKey:@"sourceRecipeUrl"], @"link",fbtextView.text, @"message", nil] andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

2) When i upload a photo with some text. The "via <**Appname**>" is clickable from my **Home** feed only but not from **Profile** feed.

```
[FB requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: imageData,@"source",fbtextView.text, @"message", nil] andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Is this the actual scenario or am i missing something. PLease help.

Comment: I want to do the same, did u get any solution?

Comment: not yet. will surely post here if I get anything. Do you have any documentation or research on this.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried checking out this setting on your Facebook App:

[image: Facebook App Settings]

It wasn't tested, but maybe you can try enabling and disabling this setting to check if it changes your result.